# Mail account problems in Microsoft Lumia 535

Tags: gmail, windows-mobile

Why cant I compose a mail from my Lumia 535 ?

In **Settings** on **Add account** part I have added my Gmail accounts. Here incoming is very ok but cant send one. Is there any solution???

And there also another problem is that I cant find the files such as **documents, zip file** when *downloaded* from this mails.

Help needed.